# How can I format Date with Locale in Android

Tags: android, date, locale

I am using SimpleDateFormat to format my date "dd Mmm yyy" format but I want Mmm to be translated to Malay. I am using below code to do so but unable to get the expected result.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format,new Locale("ms","MY"));
return sdf.format(date);
```

Comment: Why do you use "Y" instead of "y" ? Please contact the javadoc for the difference (key word: week-based-year).

Comment: That was a typo. format being used is "dd MMM yyyy"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if below code works for you, its written in Scala its almost same in Java.

```
val malaysia = new Locale("ms","MY","MY")
val cal = Calendar.getInstance(malaysia)
val df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.FULL, malaysia)
println(df.format(cal.getTime()))
```

results from above code is

```
Isnin 23 Mei 2016 9:55:44 AM IST
```

Answer (score 5):

**You Should Try This Way to format locale date:**

```
DateFormat f = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
String formattedDate = f.format(new Date());
System.out.println("Date: " + formattedDate);
```

I Hope this will work. Reference link: [Localized date format in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853150/localized-date-format-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

I had not set new Locale constructor properly to handle Malay language support.

```
String format = "MMM dd yyyy"
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, new Locale("ms","MY","MY"));
return sdf.format(date);
```

Answer (score 3):

## java.time

You are using old date-time classes that have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. They have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. Defined by JSR 310. Much of that functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project and further adapted to Android in the [ThreeTenABP project](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

If you have a java.util.Date object, convert it to an [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) object, a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds. New methods have been added to the old classes to facilitate conversion.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant();
```

Or get the current moment. In Java 8, the current moment is captured only with millisecond resolution, despite the `Instant` class’ capacity for nanoseconds. In Java 9, the current moment is captured with up to nanosecond resolution (depending on your computer hardware clock capability).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Apply a time zone for the locality whose wall-clock time you want to see. This is important even for a date-only value as the date varies around the world at any given moment. A new day dawns earlier in the east.

I choose a New Zealand time zone arbitrarily, for demonstration. Apply a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), never the 3-4 letter codes you see in the media such as `IST` or `EST`. Such codes are not standardized nor even unique.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

The time zone has nothing to do with localization into a human language such as Malay. A [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) handles that, as well as defining cultural norms to use for issues such as ordering of the elements or using period vs comma.

My example assumes you were correct in specifying the language and country/culture codes.

```
Locale locale = new Locale( "ms" , "MY" );
```

The [java.time.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) package has classes that can automatically localize when generating a String to represent a java.time value.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM );
```

When defining a formatter, remember to specify the [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). If omitted, your JVM’s current default Locale will be applied implicitly. That default can change at any moment, even during runtime! So better to be always be explicit.

```
formatter = formatter.withLocale( locale );
String output = zdt.format( formatter );
```

> 23 Mei 2016

By comparison when using [`Locale.US`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#US):

> May 23, 2016

And when using [`Locale.CANADA_FRENCH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#CANADA_FRENCH):

> 2016-05-23

Comment: ZonedDateTime requires API 26.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this way;

**Edit 1:**

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, new Locale("ms","MY"));
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

Hope this would help you.

Comment: I want to set Locale programmatically to ms_MY not the default device locale.

Comment: Need to set Locale constructor properly.

DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, new Locale("ms","MY", "MY"));
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(new Date());

Answer (score 1):

This code solved my problem and get the result in Bengali.

```
val local = Locale("bn")
val dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, local)
val stringDate = dateFormat.format(date)
Log.e("", stringDate)
```

And the output is:

> মঙ্গলবার, ২৩ ফেব্রুয়ারী, ২০২১

Answer (score 0):

if you want your date to be formatted to device locale then use the below code

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date newDate = format.parse(strDate2);
        long milliDate = newDate.getTime()+getCurrentTimezoneOffset();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(milliDate);
        return format.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: What is getCurrentTimezoneOffset() ?